# «Неплохая идея, должен признать». Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

*Неплохая идея(,) должен признать.*
Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении, если да, то почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сочетание **должен признать** может быть как членом предложения, составным глагольным сказуемым, так и вводным сочетанием (в этом случае оно не является членом предложения, его можно изъять или переставить).

**Сказуемое** (без запятой)

[Я; ты; он] *Должен признать,* (что?) *что это неплохая идея.*

― Я старался отвести справедливый гнев рузов как можно дальше от твоих великих замыслов, но с горечью ***должен признать***, что мне это не удалось… [Борис Васильев. Вещий Олег (1996)]

**Вводное сочетание** (наше предложение; задать вопрос невозможно; **ставим запятую**)

*Неплохая идея, должен признать.*
*Неплохая, должен признать, идея* (с перестановкой).

К сожалению, ваши новые сандалеты лишили нас одной из таких улик, но сам факт перемены обуви, особенно в таких условиях, тоже свидетельствует против вас. Опять же косвенно, ***должен признать***... [Еремей Парнов. Третий глаз Шивы (1985)]

В качестве примера приведу интересный, по моему мнению, отрывок, в котором имеются **три** вводных сочетания (в других контекстах они могут быть членами предложения).

> — Да, — пpизнал он. — Что да — то да. Так вот, возвращаясь к инфаркту... Работа, **должен признать**, безукоризненная. Но с баржей, **воля ваша**... того... переборщили. Нет, я прекрасно вас понимаю. Бушлаты — на дне. Тот, кто списывал, суду уже не подлежит. Полковник Непалимый, **сами видите**, по гроб жизни вам благодарен...
> [Е. Лукин. Там, за Ахероном](https://books.google.ee/books?id=4o8azKsdsp4C&pg=PT32&lpg=PT32&dq=%E2%80%95%20%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%E2%80%95%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0.%20%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82,%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%E2%80%A6%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0,%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=coSmKXVPgt&sig=ACfU3U2EMyXTuvRM5b4OuSPvT1C6lvLZpA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvn7Dtmo7yAhXll4sKHfagC90Q6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%95%20%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%E2%80%95%20%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0.%20%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%E2%80%A6%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F&f=false)

[Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)
[Должен признать](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&req=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&g=i_doc&format=html&spp=50&text=lexform&dpp=10&kwsz=5&p=5&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) (Нацкорпус)

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна: это СПП (сложноподчинённое предложение) несколько необычного вида, поскольку главная часть ("должен признать") здесь стоит второй, а придаточная ("неплохая идея") — первой; кроме того, обе части — односоставные предложения (главная — односоставное определённо-личное, придаточная — номинативное), и всё это может сбить с толку. Тем не менее это СПП, и запятая здесь положена.

Формально главное предложение — НЕОПРЕДЕЛЁННО-личное: подлежащего нет, а по сказуемому не определить, кто именно "должен признать". Но когда о подлежащем — известном говорящему! — умалчивают, из контекста оно формально не вычитывается, а сказуемое не есть глагол в настоящем времени ("Знаешь, я читала, что бессмертны души"), то можно ручаться, что подразумеваемое подлежащее — "я".

Comment: Римма Михайлова, я не вижу никаких причин считать "должен признать" вводным сочетанием, что бы это выражение ни означало: в тех случаях, когда "должен признать" не сложное сказуемое, оно - односоставное предложение. Которое в качестве придаточной части может стоять в любом месте СПП, в том числе внутри главного предложения.

Comment: Где вы увидели СПП?

Comment: В предложении "Неплохая идея, должен признать". А что: вы его там не увидели? Странно... Может, вам стоит посмотреть внимательнее?

Comment: Да? А где союз? Покажите литературу, где придаточная часть присоединяется к главной без союза.

Comment: Каким же образом вам "показать литературу"? Вы требуете фотографий со страниц?

Comment: Как каким образом? Ссылку можно дать

Comment: Ссылку на что? Ссылка на бессоюзное сложное предложение из классического автора подойдёт?

Comment: Зачем мне бессоюзное? Вы говорили, что это предложение СПП.Так? А теперь предлагаете ссылку на БСП.

Comment: Уважаемый Серж, вы этого, видимо, не знаете, но среди лингвистов есть мнение (и я его разделяю), что бессоюзные предложения с изъяснительно-объектными отношениями есть всего лишь стилистически экспрессивные варианты сложноподчинённых предложений с изъяснительными придаточными. Тем более, в нашем предложении можно однозначно восстановить союз («что»). Наше предложение несколько своеобразно только тем, что в нём сказуемое («должен признать») содержится во второй части, а указание на объект («идея») — в первой.

Comment: А если признать, что бессоюзное сложное предложение — самостоятельный тип, то немедленно возникает вопрос: а что считать «бессоюзием»? Можно ли считать бессоюзным предложение, где союз однозначно подразумевается и легко восстанавливается?

Comment: Вы сперва разберитесь, что такое БСП, а потом можете разделять чьи-то мнения или не разделять.  На этом считаю законченном нашу дискуссию, т.к. развернутые комментарии запрещены правилами  сайта.

Comment: Я знаю, что понимается под термином БСП. Жду вашего определения, «что такое БСП»)