# Запятые. Нужны ли?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> *— Вам купить игрушек? — Петя сказал не нужны нам игрушки*

Здравствуйте? Скажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли в этом предложении запятые?

> *— Ты справишься завтра в школе? — Думаю(,) справлюсь*

А здесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы оформила эти группы предложений в форме диалога (каждая реплика — с абзаца).
В конце предложения необходима точка.

1. *— Вам купить игрушек?

   — Петя сказал,* [что] *не нужны нам игрушки.*

Запятая ставится, потому что это предложение с косвенной речью. В разговорном варианте просто пропущен союз "что".

[Косвенная речь в русском языке](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kosvennaya-rech-v-russkom-yazyke.html)

2. *— Ты справишься завтра в школе?

   — Думаю, справлюсь.*

Здесь тоже запятая ставится, так как "думаю" — это вводное слово со значением *наверное, кажется, возможно, полагаю*. Его можно изъять из предложения без потери смысла.

― Я сейчас за набором съезжу и вернусь, ― услышал Кирилл голос Ромыча. ― **Думаю, справимся.** Поломка ― ерунда, но трудно добраться. [Алексей Иванов (Алексей Маврин). Псоглавцы. Гл. 1-20 (2011)]

Но тут делать нечего, как-нибудь, **думаю, справлюсь.** [Андрей Некрасов. Приключения капитана Врунгеля (1937-1939)]

[Выделение слова «думаю» запятыми](https://znanieinfo.ru/punktuatsiya/dumayu-nuzhna-li-zapyataya-do-i-posle-slova-ili-net.html)

Comment: Спасибо! А если написать в начале предложения Я, будет необходимо поставить две запятых (Я, думаю, справлюсь) или можно обойтись одной (Я думаю, справлюсь)?

Comment: *Думаю, считаю, полагаю...* Чтобы однозначно сказать, *как именно* необходимо расставить запятые, надо видеть контекст. Иногда сам автор выбирает пунктуационное оформление — ведь от этого зависит смысл, авторская идея. Посмотрите вот  здесь, возможно, что-то пригодится. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/467031/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f)